# Generate rig produces a "bugged" controller

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm having a really weird problem. I added a metarig to the scene, edited the pose to fit my character,, apply it as the rest pose, applied loc/rot/scale, and Generated Rig. The problem is that on the rig that it generates there is a "bugged" controller in the image below.

[image]

On the left side is the controller in rest mode in the forward position where it should be. On the right side is the controller in pose mode where it slightly rotates on the Z axis, despite it being locked.

I thought the solution would just be to alt+R and G to reset rotation and movement but for some reason these controllers will not reset to the rest mode. And I don't know of any other way to apply the pose mode position to these. Even when I go to the skeleton layer that controls the problem controller I can't fix it because you can't move the actual bone in pose mode and it goes to the rest pose in edit mode.
Does anyone know why this happens and/or how to resolve it?

Edit: just realized it causes problems with the hand bones and toe bone as well.

EDIT2: Here is the file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jk5RvFQrdlHRr4Pruz8Sk9br0QX3_IYm/view?usp=sharing
You can see how the rig adjusts itself by going from the rest position to the pose position in pose mode.

Comment: I noticed it too! I deleted the rig and generated a new one and that fixed it for me. Is this an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into your file and noticed the problem. I looked to the knee of the metarig and it looks like your knee is facing backwards. You can see that because the pole is backwards. I posted several pics explaining this. That is why the IK is snapping weirdly when rotating the foot. I removed the rig and generated a new one using your metarig and it seems to have fixed the snapping issue. But there are several other issues with this rig.

[image][image]

While I'm a it, I would suggest you to move the kneecaps a bit to the front, so you're knees won't bend to the back when lifting the IK Foot.

[image]
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent response, thanks so much. I do have a more broad question; is it normal to have some minor discrepancies between pose and rest mode when using the rigify system? I've went ahead and made some changes to my metarig and its fixed it for the most part, but I still notice some small, negligible rotations on a few bones between the two. I'm wondering if this is normal for such a versatile, catch-all system or if the goal should be perfect symmetry between the two (pose and rest mode).

Comment: @LuckyCOINNNN
Nice to hear! I have had those issues myself. Normally when generating from a metarig, this is not suposed to happen.
I used a rig for a long time and lost my original metarig. Meantime I made some changes to the new rig and I too am facing this dicrepencany now. Especially on the knees when using the IK. But it doens't has influence on the end results and the rig moves just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In Pose Mode and Skeleton to Pose Position select all widgets/bones and press
Pose > Apply > Apply pose as rest pose